# Show there is a unique solution

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I came across this problem.

For $X=(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$, define $A(X)=(x_1^2-x_2^2-x_3^2-x_4^2,2x_1x_2,2x_1x_3,2x_1x_4)$. For any $Z\in\mathbb{R}^4$ with $|Z|\leq 1/16$ prove that the equation $X-A(X)=Z$ has a unique solution such that $|X|\leq 1/8$. $|X|$ is the Euclidean norm of $X$.

My thought is to use the inverse function theorem. Let $I$ be the identity on $\mathbb{R}^4$. the derivative of $I-A$ is $\begin{bmatrix}1-2x_1 & -2x_2 & -2x_3 & -2x_4\\ -2x_2 & 1-2x_1 & 0 & 0\\ -2x_3 & 0 & 1-2x_1 & 0\\ -2x_4 & 0 & 0 & 1-2x_1 \end{bmatrix}$. The determinant is

$(1-2x_1)^2((1-2x_1)^2-4x_2^2-4x_3^2-4x_4)$. So this quantity needs to be nonzero for $|X|\leq 1/8$? And if this is true, $I-A$ is bijective from the ball of radius $1/8$ onto its image. So I'd then have to show that the image of this ball is contains the ball of radius $1/16$? Is this the idea?

Comment: Looks more like an exercise related to the Banach fixed point theorem.

Comment: Is $|Z| = \sqrt{z_1^2+z_2^2+z_3^2+z_4^2}$ or some another norm?

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov yes, it is the Euclidean norm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $X=(t,{\bf x})$ and $Z=(s,{\bf z})$ with ${\bf x}, {\bf z}\in{\mathbb R}^3$. Then
$$A(X)=(t^2-|{\bf x}|^2, 2t{\bf x})\ ,$$
and the equation $X-A(X)=Z$ expands to
$$\bigl(t-t^2+|{\bf x}|^2, (1-2t){\bf x}\bigr)=(s,{\bf z})\ .$$
It follows that necessarily
$${\bf x}={1\over1-2t}{\bf z}\ ,$$
which is unproblematic as long as $|t|<{1\over2}$. In addition we now have the following scalar equation for $t$:
$$t-t^2+{z^2\over(1-2t)^2}=s\ ,\tag{1}$$
which we have to solve for given $Z$ with $|s|\leq{1\over16}$, $\>z:=|{\bf z}|\leq{1\over16}$. Put
$$f(t,s,z):= t-t^2+{z^2\over(1-2t)^2}-s\ .$$
Then $f(0,0,0)=0$ and
$$f_t(0,0,0)=1+4z^2\ne0\ .$$
The implicit function theorem now allows the following conclusion: There is a neighborhood $U$ of $(s,z)=(0,0)$ and a neighborhood $V$ of $t=0$ such that for all $(s,z)\in U$ there is exactly one solution $t=\psi(s,z)\in V$ of $(1)$, whereby $\psi$ is a real analytic function of $s$ and $z$.

Of course, for exact estimates concerning the sizes of $U$ and $V$ more work is necessary. The following figure shows the graph of the LHS of $(1)$ for various values of $z$. It shows that the claim made in your question holds true.

[image]

Comment: Hi Christian, thank you for your answer. If you have time, would you mind answering a few followup questions? 1) the $y$ you have is the same as the $z$ you defined in the beginning, right? 2) You've shown $f'(0)$ can't be zero when $|s|\leq 16$ and $|y|\leq 16$. This implies there is at most one solution to (1) by Rolle's theorem. Why is there at least one? 3) Do you think an inverse function theorem approach would work for this problem? Thanks again for your answer

Answer (score 1):

Let $F(X) = X - A(X)$ and $X_0 \in \mathbb{R}^4$. By the inverse function theorem we are able to conclude that if $\det F'(X_0) \neq 0$, then there exists an open set $U_{X_0} \subset \mathbb{R}^4$ containing $X_0$ such that the function $F_0 : U_{X_0} \to F(U_{X_0}) : X \mapsto F(X)$ is bijective.

Let $\overline{B}(r) = \{ X \in \mathbb{R}^4 : |X| \le r \}$.

So given $Z \in \overline{B} \left(\frac{1}{16}\right)$, we need to find $X_0 \in \mathbb{R}^4$ such that $\det F'(X_0) \neq 0$ and $Z \in F(U_{X_0})$, such that $|\underbrace{F_0^{-1}(Z)}_{X_Z}| \le \frac{1}{8}$, and after that, we still need to show that among all points in $B \left(\frac{1}{8} \right)$, $X_Z$ is the unique point such that $F(X) = Z$.

How would we choose $X_0$ to guarantee that $U_{X_0} \cap B \left(\frac{1}{8} \right) \neq \emptyset$? Because the theorem gives us no control over $U_{X_0}$ we will need to inspect it by hand. This seems no easier than a direct computation approach.

Perhaps there is an alternative (and desirably easier) approach? Well... notice that

$$ X-A(X)=Z \iff A(X) + Z = X$$

This means that $X$ is a solution of the equation $X-A(X)=Z$ if and only if it is a fixed point of the function $G(X) = A(X) + Z$. Thus the statement is equivalent to showing that for every $Z \in \overline{B} \left(\frac{1}{16}\right)$, the function $G : \overline{B} \left(\frac{1}{8}\right) \to \overline{B} \left(\frac{1}{8}\right) : X \mapsto A(X) + Z$ is a contraction, whence it follows that it has an unique fixed point. Having in mind that $|A(X)| = |X|^2$ we see that the function $G$ is well-defined because for all $X \in \overline{B} \left(\frac{1}{8}\right)$

$$|G(X)| \le |A(X)| + |Z| = |X|^2 + |Z| \le \left( \frac{1}{8} \right)^2 + \frac{1}{16} \le \frac{1}{8} $$

Now to show that $G$ is a contraction it is enough to show that the absolute value of $G'(X)$'s eigenvalues are all less than $1$ for all $X \in \overline{B} \left(\frac{1}{8}\right)$. For that consider $\rho(A)$ the maximum absolute value of $A$'s eigenvalues and the matrix norm

$$ \|A\| = \max \{ |Av| : v \in \mathbb{R}^4, |v| = 1 \} $$

Therefore, if $X \in \overline{B} \left(\frac{1}{8}\right)$, then

$$ \rho(G'(X)) \le \|G'(X)\| = \sqrt{\rho(G'(X)^T G'(X))} = 2 |X| \le \frac{1}{4} $$

Hence the result.

*(Moreover, note that the hypothesis we were working in $4$ dimensions were not used, meaning that the exactly same proof holds for the general case of $\mathbb{R}^n$.)*

Answer (score 1):

Let 
$$S = x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2 = |X|^2 \ge 0,\tag1$$
then
$$\begin{cases}
(1-2x_1)x_1+S=z_1\\
(1-2x_1)x_2= z_2\\
(1-2x_1)x_3= z_3\\
(1-2x_1)x_4= z_4\\
\end{cases}\tag2$$
$$|Z|^2= (x_1(1-2x_1) + S)^2 + (1-2x_1)^2(S-x_1^2) = {x_1^2(1-2x_1)^2 + 2Sx_1(1-2x_1)+S^2 +(1-2x_1)^2(S-x_1^2)} = {(1-2x_1)^2S + 2Sx_1(1-2x_1)+S^2} = S^2 + (1-2x_1)S.$$
The system
$$\begin{cases}
(1-2x_1)x_1+S=z_1\\
S^2 + (1-2x_1)S = |Z|^2\\
\tag3\end{cases}$$
allows the elimination of $S:$
$$\begin{cases}
S= 2x_1^2 - x_1 + z_1\\
(2x_1^2 - x_1 + z_1)^2 - (2x_1-1)(2x_1x_2 - x_1 + z_1) = |Z|^2,
\end{cases}$$
and can be written in the form of
$$\begin{cases}
S= 2x_1^2 - x_1 + z_1\\
((2x_1 - 1)^2 + 2z_1)^2 - ((2x_1-1)^2 + 2z_1) - (4|Z|^2 -2z_1)=0\\
\end{cases}\tag4$$
Note that
$$D=\dfrac14+(4|Z|^2-2z_1) = \left(\dfrac12-2z_1\right)^2+4(|Z|^2-z_1^2) = \left(\dfrac12-2|Z|\right)^2+2(|Z|-z_1),\tag5$$
$$|z_1|\le|Z|\le\dfrac1{16},\tag6$$
so the solution of $(4)$ is
$$(2x_1-1)^2+2z_1 = \dfrac12 + \sqrt{\left(\dfrac12-2|Z|\right)^2+2(|Z|-z_1)}.\tag7$$
Then, using $(6)$ and $(7),$
$$(2x_1-1)^2 \ge 1-4|Z| \ge \dfrac34.$$
If $|2x-1>0|,$ then
$$2x_1-1 \ge \dfrac{\sqrt3}2,\quad x_1 \ge \dfrac{2+\sqrt3}4,\quad |Z|^2 \ge\dfrac{3+2\sqrt3}8 > \dfrac1{256}.$$
The contradiction means that the solution  **is unique** for any Z, which satisfies the issue condition, wherein 
$$1-2x_1 \ge \sqrt{1-4|Z|},$$
$$S^2+\sqrt{1-4|Z|}S-|Z|^2\le 0,$$
$$S\le \dfrac{-\sqrt{1-4|Z|}+\sqrt{1-4|Z|+4|Z|^2}}2 = \dfrac{2|Z|^2}{\sqrt{1-4|Z|}+1-2|Z|} \le  \dfrac{\dfrac1{128}}{\dfrac{\sqrt3}2+\dfrac78} < 
 \dfrac1{128\sqrt3},$$
$$\mathbf{|X| < \dfrac {1}{8\sqrt[4]{12}} < \dfrac18}.$$